# Append multiple Strings.xml into single xml using gradle task

Tags: android, xml, gradle, xml-parsing, android-gradle-plugin

Hi Guys so I am trying to create a single xml file from many strings xml file i have in my android gradle project this is done for some automation as the the tool can only single file hence I am trying to add all strings into a single xml for this purpose,This is how I am trying to achieve it

1. Copy and rename the main string file as needed like this

   ```
       task copyMain(type: Copy){
   from ("$rootDir/service/src/main/res/values/")
   into ("$rootDir/main_build/")
   include ('strings.xml')
   rename {String fileName -> fileName.replace("strings.xml","strings_service.xml")}
       doLast{
   println("copying strings_service.xml from values to main_build is complete");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now I want to read each of the smaller strings.xml files and append the entry into the "/main_build/strings_service.xml"
   Here but i am able to read the attributes of each strings but not the actual value

**Sample strings xml**

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <string name="auto_classify_hint_message" comment="Frequent drive hint message; no plurals as prompt always requires several drives" tools:ignore="PluralsCandidate">You have classified %1$d other drives like this&lt;br>as &lt;b>%2$s&lt;/b>.</string>
</resources>
```

These are the ways i try to read.

```
def stringXml = new XmlParser().parse("$rootDir//src/main/res/values/strings_hints.xml")

stringXml.'string'.each{ s ->
    println("line:"+s+"\n");
    println("name:"+s.@name+"\n");
    println("comment:"+s.@comment+"\n");
    println("tools1:"+s."{http://schemas.android.com/tools}ignore"+"\n")
    println("tools2:"+s.@tools:ignore+"\n")
    println("tools3:"+s.'tools:ignore'+"\n")
    println("val1:"+s.value[0]+"\n");
    println("val2:"+s@value+"\n");
    println("val3:"+s.value+"\n");
    println("\n");

}
```

The console output looks like this

```
 line:string[attributes={name=auto_classify_hint_message, comment=Frequent drive hint message; no plurals as prompt always requires several drives, {http://schemas.android.com/tools}ignore=PluralsCandidate}; value=[You have classified %1$d other drives like this<br>as <b>%2$s</b>.]]

name:auto_classify_hint_message

comment:Frequent drive hint message; no plurals as prompt always requires several drives

tools1:[]

tools2:null

tools3:[]

val1:null

val2:null

val3:[]
```

How  do i do the following

- read the "**value**"  and "**tools:ignore**" attribute it seem that  in compile time the tools get replaced by hyperlink (check println "line" in console) which is i dont want to . I just want to copy  each row of `<string> </string>`  from each of the string xml
- and append  each such row into "strings_service.xml"  under the `<resources> </resources>` tag